# How to set different tooltip and confirmation titles on the same element?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am using bootstrap-confirmation and tooltip together on the same element. I need different contents for each of them. For example one could use **confirm-title** attribute and the other one could use **tooltip-title**. Right now they both use the **title** attribute in the html tag. Is there a way to change the default?

Here is what i have: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqccrujg/1/)

In this example both confirmaion and tooltip use the title attribute. But as i said i want them to use two different attributes.

I know that i could use two different nested tags for each, like:

```
<a href='#' title="text1" ...><span title="text2" ...> button </span></a>
```

But what i am looking for is to use a single tag by changing the source of the text.

Comment: can you post what have you done...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do **exactly** what you want using **tooltip-title** and **confirm-title**. Do this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#Delete" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" tooltip-title="Tooltip title" confirm-title="Confirmation title" confirmation tooltip data-singleton="true" data-placement="top" data-popout="true">Click Me</a>
```

JS:

```
// Uses 'tooltip-title' as title
$('a[tooltip]').tooltip({title: function() {
    return $(this).attr("tooltip-title");
}});

// Uses 'confirm-title' attribute for title
$('a[confirmation]').confirmation({title: function() {
    return $(this).attr("confirm-title");
}});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Drakes/wqccrujg/7/

Answer (score 1):

you could set the title with js, if thats an option:

```
 $(".tip-top").tooltip({title : 'Your Title'});
```

Comment: nope that is not what i mean. i added a jsfiddle example.